# We don't need no [education]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

At the moment we have the following tags from the topic field "education":

- [teaching](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching): 0 followers, 10 questions

  > Questions about teaching chess, chess strategies etc.
- [learning](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning): 23 followers, 241 questions, synonym: [improvement](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/improvement)

  > Questions related to learning how to play chess and improving your chess skills
- [education](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education): 0 followers, 8 questions

  > *There is no usage guidance for this tag … yet!*

I think [education](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education) is a tag to much, all topics about education should be sufficiently described using [teaching](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) or [learning](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning).

Therefore I think we should retag all questions tagged with [education](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education) using one (or two) of the other "education" topic field tags and delete [education](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education).

Comment: [teaching] and [learning] should come under the broader tag [education] in my opinion. They're both just another brick in the wall...

Comment: Yes, that would be another good idea I haven't really thought of yet.

Comment: `learning` can have a different meaning in the context of computer chess. `edcuation` and `teaching` can be made synonyms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments, I would propose the following idea (edits to existing tags are *emphasized*)

- [teaching](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching)

  > Questions about teaching chess, chess strategies etc.
- [learning](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning)

  > Questions related to learning how to play chess and improving your chess skills. *This can also be used for questions concerning "learning" chess engines.*
- [education](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education) *gets deleted*

I will retag questions tagged with [education](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education) using [teaching](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) or [learning](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) and extend the tag excerpt of [learning](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning), both under reference to this answer.